# python twisted: How to send session id when a new client connects?

Tags: python, tcp, twisted, xml-rpc

So I have a server that sends data over TCP, that clients can connect to. I want to add an XMLRPC functionality, but the xmlrpc calls will come on a different connection. So there are two connections that each client has with the server, one is the TCP server and the other is the xmlrpc. So if the client makes some xmlrpc request I can't figure out exactly what is the TCP connection of the client that requested the rpc.

To solve this I plan to **pass a uuid that I will pass to the client when he first makes the connection**. Any calls the client makes must pass this uuid for verification.

**My question.** How to write a call back that takes the uuid when the client connects to the server and it also receives data? I want to write this on client side.

Comment: What have you tried? Hard to know what to suggest without some context of what your protocols and such look like. Another idea you could try is having the client send the uuid to the server and have the server establish a session for that id that could link the two connections.

Comment: I send a uuid when the connection is made. But the client code has to have a flag to judge that it has received the uuid. Is there anyway I can get rid of the flag